# Microformats, reviews and duplicate content

Tags: seo, google-search, duplicate-content, microformats

Let's say I have a site that sells widgets, and the URL structure is like so:

```
/[type-of-widget]/[sub-type]/[widget-name]/
```

So, a URL for a widget might be:

```
/screwdrivers/philips-screwdrivers/acme-big-screwdriver/
```

We show reviews on the widget page, and use the appropriate Microformats data so Google knows it's a review, etc.

Now, what if I want to show random reviews in the "sub-type" and "type-of-widget" landing pages? Will Google ding me for duplicate content, or is it smart enough to know (based on Microformat data etc.) that this is not duplicate content?

Answer (score 1):

Showing content that you own in a couple places on your site will generally not hurt you.  In the worst case, Google will not index one of the two places that content appears.

Duplicate content can become an issue that can get your whole site in trouble when

- You have no content of your own, you are only syndicating content from other sources
- Much of your content is duplicated across 100s of pages with no other unique content on those pages

Google's Matt Cutts just [addressed duplicate content for boilerplate such as legal notices](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vi-wkEeOKxM) that have to be on lots of pages.  He says that he wouldn't stress about duplicate content.    Unless your content is spammy or keyword stuffing, then it shouldn't be anything to worry about if it appears in multiple locations on your site.